# VBA cannot correctly handle range returned by find method

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim Text_Cell As Range
Dim temp As Control

Set Text_Cell = Sheet1.Cells.Find("Text")

Do Until Text_Cell.Offset(1, 0).Value = ""
    Set temp = UserForm1.MultiPage(1).Controls.Add("Forms.Commandbutton.1", "h")

    Set Text_Cell = text_Cell.Offset(1, 0)
Loop
```

EDIT: Just a quick clarification - using MsgBoxes, breakpoints, science, magic, etc. I found out the cause of the "Object required" error occurs well before VBA gets to the loop.

I am trying to find a cell in a sheet that has the value of "text" then for each cell with a value below it - create a control on my userform. The problem I am having is that the Find method finds the correct cell, returns and assigns it but for some reason VBA cannot handle the "text_Cell" variable, even though after setting a breakpoint and taking a look at the local variable of "text_Cell" I saw it is assigned to the proper cell. I keep getting "Object Required" error. Getting the cell alone returns nothing, hence trying to reference Offst(1,0) raises the "Object required" error.

Comment: You are finding *text* then looping through all of the blank cells underneath it. Are you sure you don't want all of the non-blank cells underneath it?

Comment: @Jeeped, yes, thank you, my mistake. I will fix that but the original problem lies outside the loop

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your issue with your example. Have you tested it?

Comment: @FlorentB., yes, numerous times. I couldn't find anything about it on the net, to me everything seems completely fine. This usually means it is something extremely trivial that I am overlooking.

Comment: Try your example with a new workbook and a new form and you'll see that it works. Moreover your example is not what you tested since the case of the last variable (text_Cell) is different from the declaration (Text_Cell).

Comment: @mathgenius, That was my point, the case should have been corrected by the IDE which isn't in your example. My intention wasn't to to be rude. Just trying to help here.

Comment: I guess that `Sheet1` is either to be set (some `set Sheet1 = ...`) or substituted with some `Thisworkbook.Worksheet("Sheet1")` or  `Thisworkbook.Worksheet(1)` whatever should be your case

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to find a cell in a sheet that has the value of "text" then for **each cell with a value below it** - create a control on my userform.

Use the following to cycle through all of the **non-blank** cells beneath the cell with *text*.

```
Set Text_Cell = Sheet1.Cells.Find(What:="text", MatchCase:=False, _
                              LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlFormulas)

Do Until Text_Cell.Value = ""
    Set temp = UserForm1.MultiPage(1).Controls.Add("Forms.Commandbutton.1", "h")

    Set text_Cell = text_Cell.Offset(1, 0)
Loop
```

Comment: Thank you for noticing that. I will appreciate it if you notice my primary problem, as well.

Comment: The [Range.Find method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) has a 'memory' as to any parameters not explictly set 'remembered' from the previous use (even from the worksheet). I've adjusted the above to cover some of the more important options.

Comment: It's not that. First off, as I have stated, the method works fine, the variable "text_cell" is even storing the cell, yet I get "Object required" error. Second, unless the settings are remembered even after the whole of excel is closed, they are not an issue, at all.